# Jenkins chart to show historic job runs

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Is there a Jenkins time chart / plugin that shows when all Jenkin jobs start and end 
for historic job runs

It would show when Jenkins jobs run in parallel

i.e. something like a Gantt chart but for historic job runs

Answer (score 4):

There is the build history which is available in the side bar from the jenkins start page (e.g. `http://<jenkins-host>/view/All/builds`), it shows the builds, when it runs, which status the builds completed with and links to the console. It also comes with a graph that allows to browse through time.

Answer (score 0):

All/builds is a mess...
There is no proper plugin in Jenkins to see historic jobs.